# How to conditionally redirect to a custom scheme URL in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache configured like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/launchApp$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android
# Here I want to redirect to an URL with a custom scheme
```

The `RewriteRule` does not work form custom schemes (in my case `mobile://...`)

The PHP module is loaded in my Apache, then I thought about a solution like redirecting to a local URL serving a file like:

```
<?php
  header("Location: mobile://...");
?>
```

But I don't like the idea of achieving this by forwading the HTTP request to a local one, and it causes problems with the rest of my configuration.

How to conditionally redirect to a custom scheme URL in Apache?

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule (.*) mobile://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`

Comment: @FAEWZX that doesn't work, the custom scheme URL is considered as a relative one and is appended at the end of the current URL

Answer (score 0):

I found a satisfying solution, which uses a shell script and allows not to proxy the request, by referring directly to a filesystem path:

I've created the file `/var/www/cgi-bin/redirectToMobile.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh -f

echo "Status: 302 Found"
echo "Location: mobile://..."
echo ""
```

And then the following Apache conf:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/launchApp$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android
RewriteRule ^.*$ /var/www/cgi-bin/redirectToMobile.sh [L]

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        AddHandler cgi-script .sh
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```